# Ignore directory if matching filename exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

..To make pretty URLs for my .html files.

Assuming a directory structure like this:

```
/services/service-one.html
/services/service-two.html
/services.html
/something-else.html
```

`service-one.html`, `service-two.html` & `something-else.html` all work properly, but I can't get `services.html` to load using the `/services` URL because there is a directory matching the name.

Is there a way that this behaviour can be changed so that `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f` works regardless of the URL matching a directory?  Or maybe another way of achieving the same result?

Thanks!

**Edit**

After removing my .htaccess and finding those non-.html links still work, I had a look in my VirtualHost and wonder if it is something in there causing it?  I can see that MultiViews is what's giving me the URL rewrite behaviour that I wanted to achieve in the .htaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/mysite"
    ServerName testsite.com
     <Directory "/mysite">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
     </Directory>
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit 2**

Behaviour remains the same with no `MultiViews`, and using *Anonymous*'s `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. The reason this rule is not working is that you require a trailing slash to add the *.html* extension. You can just remove that requirement in the rewrite regex:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L]
   ```
2. The better way to do this is to create a file named *index.html* in the *services* directory. Then, when you request the directory without a filename, that file is automatically used.

---

For the first option to work, you would also need to change the default behavior. You can use this line to prevent adding a trailing slash to directories:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Comment: Hiya.  It turns out that I'm getting a 301 on that request, which adds a trailing slash to the URL. I deleted the .htaccess only to see that the other pages still work without .html.  MultiViews was set in my VirtualHost, so I am wondering if that is the cause?  I'll edit my .conf in to my question.

Comment: Yes, that is probably because of MultiViews.

Comment: I removed MultiViews & the .htaccess to confirm that there's no more pretty URL rewriting, then added your .htaccess suggestion again, and the behaviour is still the same.  Something in Apache creates the 301 to the directory.

Comment: I missed that part of your previous comment. Updated

Comment: It's working perfectly now.  Thank you for your help :)